# Count number of value occurrences per column in matrix - R

Tags: r

I have a matrix in R that is structured like so:

ColA     ColB     ColC
5            7           12
9             8              3
15          0             25

I'd like to find, for each column, the number of values greater than 10, such that I would get a vector (or data frame?) showing this result:

ColA    1
ColB    0
ColC    2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
colSums(m1 >=10)
# ColA ColB ColC 
#  1    0    2
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
m1 %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum(.>=10)))
#  ColA ColB ColC
#1    1    0    2
```